# Consumir API GoToWebinar con Token de acceso-OAuth2.0- Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, oauth2, oauth

estoy intentado conectarme a la API de Go To Webinar desde javascript para obtener diferentes tipos de datos en un .json, intente con fetch() pero no se donde se colocan los token de autorizacion, la documentación da estos ejemplos:

curl 
'https://api.getgo.com/admin/rest/v1/me' 
-H 'Accept: application/json' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'

No se como "convertir" esto a Javascript, lo intento con Postman y funciona perfectamente, en javascript lo intente de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro ejemplo de la documentación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo todos los tokens de autorización, código de usuario y demás, pero no se donde ingresar estos paramentaros en el código

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

no se cual sera la respuesta que te da fetch. Pero noto un que te falta response.json(), si la respuesta por consola es **function json()** deberias intentar algo como esto:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
   .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
```

O

```
const request = async () => {

let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')

if (response.ok) {
  console.log(await response.json());
} else {
   alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
  }
}

request()
```

Fetch proporciona diferentes métodos para el response:

1. response.text()
2. response.json()
3. response.formData()
4. response.blob()
5. response.arrayBuffer()

con respecto a la options que estas enviando por headers no veo errores, aunque si seguís teniendo errores podrías enviar el Authorization por post o refrescar el token. Saludos espero haberte aportado algo.